# Hibernate session factory close drops all auto generated tables

Tags: java, hibernate

Using hibernate4

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    //do some task
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
```

Using auto generated proprty

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

as you can see I am closing my session factory it drops all my tables after this code completed as I see on console. Is it the default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior for the create-drop mode.

See [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties) for more information.

Additionally, see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) for more exposition on the values.

Answer (score 1):

That's the intention of the property `create-drop`.

Use `create` or `update` to keep your tables.

Answer (score 0):

change hbm2dll.auto property in your hibernate mapping to "update" to keep the changes you do in the database.